# Cannot determine if user input is blank javascript

Tags: javascript, input

I am creating a voting system webpage using Javascript. There are several things the user must input before beginning the vote, such as candidates, number of people voting, etc. I have created a function for each one, but when I attempted to add some validating if statements to my enterCandidate function, it would not register an error when the user left the box blank. Here is the function code:

```
  var enterCandidate = prompt("Please enter a candidate");
  for (let i = 0; i < enterCandidate.length; i++){
    if (isNaN(enterCandidate.charAt(i)) || enterCandidate.charAt(i) == ' '){
      if (!enterCandidate.length == 0){
         candidates.push(enterCandidate);
         console.log(enterCandidate);
         candidate1 = candidates[0];
         candidate2 = candidates[1];
         candidate3 = candidates[2];
         candidate4 = candidates[3];
         candidate5 = candidates[4];
         candidate6 = candidates[5];
      } else {
        alert('Please do not leave the box blank.');
      }
    } else {
        alert('Please enter a name, without symbols or numbers.');
    }
  }
}
```

The part I am having an issue with is the second if statement, where I used !enterCandidate.length == 0. This should only return true if the user has inputted something but instead it returns false and moves to the else alert 'Please do not leave the box blank'. I am aware that even if this code worked, it would allow people to enter just spaces - I am not really sure how to tackle that without registering errors if people entered full names.

Comment: `if (enterCandidate.trim().length > 0)`. It's not clear at all why you're iterating through the string's characters

Comment: Go read up on [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table). `!` has a much higher precedence, than `==`.

Comment: `prompt` returns either a string or `null`, you can simply check `if (enterCandidate && enterCandidate.trim()) {...}`.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, I have tried each of them but they don't seem to work I'm afraid - I don't know why, but the alert won't appear. In answer to your question Phil, I am iterating through the characters in order to check whether each character is a letter or number - as seen in my NaN statement. Are you suggesting that I remove this in order for the code to work? Thanks.

Comment: What is the user supposed to type into the prompt?  Do they type a list of candidate names or a list of letters and numbers that reference some predefined list of candidates? Your code has multiple problems, but we can probably get you started in the right direction if you provide more detail about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have mostly been cobbling this together from w3schools and teaching myself. The user input should be a name, either one or two words. If you like I could post all of my code to help you get a better idea of how the functions interlink.

Comment: After some thought, I reversed the order so the if statement to check if the box was blank went before the for statement, and now the code works! Thanks, everyone